# Why does my web api map the get request to the second method in my api controller rather than the first one?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Why does the web api maps the request to the second method (one with the signature 'public string Get(string y ="1")'), when I send a request to 
http://localhost:55833/api/values/1

why not the first action with int x.

If I remove the second get method I get the error saying:

```
<Error>
<Message>
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
</Message>
</Error>
```

I am trying to understand why this behavior.
Below is my code.

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {

        public static List<string> values = new List<string> { "Tim","Charlie" };
        // GET api/values


        public IEnumerable<string> Get(int x)
        {
            return values;
        }

        public string Get(string y="1")
        {
            return values[1];
        }



    }
```

WebApiConfig.cs file:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the default value and you will see what happens. Use any other value than 1 and you will also see that y remains 1. The optional parameter is the reason.

Comment: I removed the default val and same thing.  The request still gets mapped to the second method.  Why does it go to the second method rather than the first one?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the parameter name in first method to ‘id’ from ‘x’ it will be called. Note in your route you have {id} fragment.

Currently, in second method the string parameter is optional so even when you call with integer id it is mapped to second method with ‘y’ parameter value as null.